# Azure container app update the container image registry and image

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-apps

I am working on Azure container app. I have already created the container app from Azure portal with the default image which is from DockerHub registry.

But Now I want to deploy actual code to that container app and I am using `az containerapp update` , In github action but I am getting the error

```
ERROR: (InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate) The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'template.containers.simple-hello-world-container.image' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "***/demo-api:1.0.1": GET https:?scope=repository%3Ademo-api%3Apull&service=***: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.';
```

other config are updated to that container but image and image registry is not changed.
Here is my github action command

- name: Azure Deploy App
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
  inlineScript: |
  az containerapp update 
  --name ca-demoapi 
  --resource-group rg-ca 
  --image ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}/${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }}
  --cpu 1.0 
  --memory 2.0Gi 
  --min-replicas 0 
  --max-replicas 2 
  --scale-rule-name http-rule-10-req 
  --scale-rule-type http 
  --scale-rule-http-concurrency 10
  --container-name ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }} 
  --ingress 'external'

Complete Github action, which build image, push to ACR and then deploy

```
on: push 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Load dotenv
      id: dotenv
      uses: falti/dotenv-action@v1.0.4
      with:
        path: .env
        log-variables: true
        export-variables: true
        keys-case: bypass
    
    - name: Log into Azure Container Registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        registry: ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        password: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }}

    - name: Build image
      run: |        
        docker build \
          -t ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }} .

    - name: Re-Tag image For ACR
      run: |
        docker tag ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }} ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}/${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }}
    
    - name: Push image to ACR
      run: |
        docker push ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}/${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }}

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Load dotenv
      id: dotenv
      uses: falti/dotenv-action@v1.0.4
      with:
        path: .env
        log-variables: true
        export-variables: true
        keys-case: bypass

    - name: Azure login  
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Azure Deploy App
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: |
          az containerapp update \
          --name ca-demoapi \
          --resource-group rg-ca \
          --image ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}/${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_TAG }}
          --cpu 1.0 \
          --memory 2.0Gi \
          --min-replicas 0 \
          --max-replicas 2 \
          --scale-rule-name http-rule-10-req \
          --scale-rule-type http \
          --scale-rule-http-concurrency 10   
          --container-name ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.IMAGE_NAME }} \
          --ingress 'external' 


    - name: Azure CLI script
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: |
          az logout
          az cache purge
          az account clear
```

So how can i update the image of the container in CI/ CD pipeline?

Comment: you need to configure the registry to use: `az containerapp registry` first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/registry?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: @Thomas Can you elaborate more?